# can we describe every integer $\gt 1$ using only prime numbers, but not in the way you expect?

Tags: prime-factorization

for $a,b \in \mathbb{N}^+$, define:
$$ a \circ b = a^b
$$
and for any positive integer $n$ define its *quadratfrei* radical  $n^{\sqrt{}}$ (the product of all distinct primes dividing n) by
$$
n^{\sqrt{}}= max  \{k \in \mathbb{N}^+ \mid (k \mid n) \land (\forall j \lt k, \; j^2 \not \mid k \}
$$
we note that:
$$
a^{\sqrt{}} = (a \circ b)^{\sqrt{}}
$$

let $\mathfrak{P}$ denote the set of primes of $\mathbb{N}$ and define the set of numbers $P$ by the following three rules.

(a)  $\mathfrak{P} \subset P$

(b)  if $\mathfrak{p} \in \mathfrak{P}$ and $b \in P$ then $\mathfrak{p} \circ b \in P$

(c) if $a,b \in P$ and $(ab)^{\sqrt{}}=a^{\sqrt{}}b^{\sqrt{}}$ then $ab\in P$

the purport of the condition in rule (c) is to require that $a^{\sqrt{}}$ and $b^{\sqrt{}}$ have no prime factor in common.

am i correct in asserting that $P=\mathbb{N}^+ \setminus \{1\}$, and that the formation rules produce a unique representation of every integer $\gt 1$, which *uses only prime numbers*?

Comment: Am I understanding your definition of $n^{\sqrt{}}$? It seems to me that $n^{\sqrt{}}=1$ for every positive integer $n$. Do you mean instead to define $n^{\sqrt{}}= \min \{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+: j^2 \mid n {\textrm{  and }} j>1\}$? Also, can you clarify what you mean by "the formation rules produce a unique representation of every integer"? If number $343=7^3$ is in $P$ by one rule that says so directly, and by another rule (depends on what you mean by $\sqrt{}$) that says so because $7^3=7\cdot7^2$, what is the unique representation of $343$?

Comment: the intention of the definition of radical (which I assume fairly standard) is to map each integer $\gt 1$ to its largest quadratfrei divisor. the condition (c) therefore rules out your second proposed derivation of $343$

Comment: Your intended definition of the radical of $n$ will be clearer if you state it in words rather than a string of symbols. Also, if you don't mean the standard radical (product of all distinct primes dividing $n$), you should use a different term.

Comment: @GregMartin thx Greg, i'll edit in your definition

Comment: thx Steve and Greg for helping me to clarify my question

Comment: Thanks. I'd misread it, and the clarification helps.

Comment: Is $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ perhaps a simpler way to express condition c)? If it's the same (a and b have no prime factor in common if and only if they have no nontrivial factor in common), I think it will be better understood. The question doesn't use the quadratfrei radical otherwise, so its definition could be omitted.

Comment: Aren't $16=2\circ 4$ and $16=4\circ 2$ two different representations of $16$?  (Where $2$ is prime and $4=2\circ 2$.)

Comment: @mjqxxxx how do you get $4 \circ 2$ from the three rules?

Comment: However it breaks down syntactically, it seems clear that the result of this is going to be the classic 'factor $n$ into a product of prime powers, then factor each of the exponents in those prime powers into a product of prime powers, etc.', and it seems like it shouldn't be hard to build an inductive proof.

Comment: Don't you mean (b) to be: "if $\mathfrak{p} \in \mathfrak{P}$ and $b \in P$ then $\mathfrak{p} \circ b \in P$", so that $\mathfrak{p}$ must be a prime?

Comment: Jeppe - I think you're right. In the comments to my answer, David even convinced me that's what he _said_, even though it's only what I think he _meant_.

Comment: As others are pointing out, you get $4\circ 2$ from the three rules as written, because rule (b) says that the base and the exponent only need to be in $P$.  But maybe you meant to say that the base must be actually be prime?

Comment: yes, both right. I was so convinced of what I said, I didn't look carefully. I will edit that awful typo. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any $n$. By the usual version of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, there exist distinct primes $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_r$ and corresponding exponents $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_r$, so that

$$n=a_1^{b_1} a_2^{b_2} a_3^{b_3} \dots a_r^{b_r}$$

Now, all the $a_i$ are already primes, while some of the $b_i$ may be prime, some may be composite, and some may be $1$. Leave the *primes* $b_i$ as they stand. Substitute the composite $b_i$ with *their* expansions by the fundamental theorem. Erase the ones. As an example this could give

$$n=a_1^{b_1} a_2^{c_{21}^{d_{21}} c_{22}^{d_{22}} c_{23}^{d_{23}} \dots c_{2q}^{d_{2q}}} a_3 \dots a_r^{c_{r1}^{d_{r1}} c_{r2}^{d_{r2}} c_{r3}^{d_{r3}} \dots c_{rp}^{d_{rp}}}$$

Now all the remaining $b_i$ are prime, and all the $c_{ij}$ are prime. But some $d_{ij}$ may be composite, and we substitute them, and so on.

It is clear that this process will end, because each component (each prime and each exponent) in the expansion of a composite number is less than that composite number itself.

So eventually we reach in this way a "representation" where all numbers in all "superscript levels" are primes. Was this the representation you wanted to describe?

Comment: yes, I was fairly confident that the assertion was true, for the "descending chain" reasons outlined in your proof. but I have been casting about for some time for the appropriate description of the situation, so I am very glad to have found the three rules described. they are so economical (for the problem as stipulated) that I feel they must be somehow "natural". thank you for your interest, and congratulations on your insight (and on your notational cojones)! ;-|)

Answer (score 3):

<s>Here's a shot at a proof. Either</s> I'm missing something <s>or it's fairly simple.</s>

**Added: This isn't a proof of what David meant (but didn't precisely say in the question)**, since as David points out, it uses what rule b) is supposed to say incorrectly. To give an example: For $k=4$, $k^{\sqrt{}} \not \in \mathfrak{P}$. The incorrect argument below would have claimed $7^4\in P$ by writing $4=2\cdot2$, then using rule b) twice. First, $7^2\in P$, which is a correct application, then to say $(7^2)^2\in P$, which is an incorrect application of b), which only allows the base to be a prime (not an arbitrary element of $P$).

While $7^4$ is in $P$, the reason I gave was wrong. It requires first showing that $4\in P$ and working "from the top down", not "from the bottom up" of the power of exponents. I don't see a quick way to show this can be done in general.

Invalid proof:

First, show that $p^k$ will be in $P$ for any prime $p$ and positive integer $k$. Suppose $k$ factors into $r$-many primes as $k=q_1\cdots q_r$. Then $\displaystyle p^k=\left(\cdots\left({(p^{q_1})}^{q_2}\right)\dots \right)^{q_r}$ is in $P$ by repeated applications of rule b).

Every integer $n$ is a product of powers of distinct primes, each of which is now known to be in $P$. Using that decomposition of any $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, rule c) will guarantee that $n\in P$.

Comment: I think that if $k^{\sqrt{}} \not \in \mathfrak{P}$, you can only get $p^{k}$ by an application of rule (b), which only allows a prime as base, though the exponent can be any element of $P$

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer (which is no longer an answer) to explain.

Comment: I see you've twigged that now. I feared my comment might not be much help. thank you for your interest in this question

Comment: Aha - as Jeppe points out, your question doesn't require the base to be a prime, so I think my original proof was a correct proof of what you posted, but it didn't prove what you wanted to ask. (Also, if you see this, what about my earlier suggestion that there's no need for the quadratfrei radical - all you need is that $a\cdot b\in P$ whenever both $a$ and $b$ are in $P$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$?)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a spin at an inductive proof:

Let $n$ be a natural number.  Then we have two distinct cases:

1. $n\in\mathfrak{P}$.  Then $n\in P$ by definition.
2. $n\not\in\mathfrak{P}$.  Then $n$ has a prime factorization: $n=p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}\ldots$, with $n_i\lt n$ and $p_i\lt n$ for all $i$.  By the induction hypothesis, $n_i\in P$, and $p_i\in \mathfrak{P}$, so we can write $n=(p_1\circ n_1)\cdot(p_2\circ n_2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(p_i\circ n_i)$.  By the induction hypothesis, all of the $n_i$ are in $P$, and we know that $\mathop{GCD}(p_i, p_j)=1$ for all $i,j$, so $n\in P$.

Comment: Steven, excellent. sorry only just seen your answer which has an hour's priority. I'm sure you won't mind me accepting Jeppe's praiseworthy exposition, given the ratio between your respective reputations. I have one or two further queries on this matter, which I hope you may offer guidance on.

Comment: Not at all!  I think the two answers complement each other nicely: his shows how the final result can be built up from the constituent primes, whereas mine merely implies the construction but is more explicit about the induction proof.

Answer (score 0):

as one step towards a formal proof of the assertion in my question it seems that we may represent the process of generating $P = \cup_{n<\omega}\; P_n$, as follows:

set $$P_0=\mathfrak{P}
$$
and for $n \ge 0$
$$P_{2n+1} = P_{2n} \cup \bigcup_{X = Im{\psi}, \psi \in P_{2n}^{\omega,\sqrt{}}}\left(\prod_{p \in X} p \right)\\
$$
[where $P_{2n}^{\omega,\sqrt{}}$ denotes all the injective maps from a finite ordinal domain into $P_{2n}$, such that any two elements of the image satisfy the condition
in rule (c)]
and
$$
P_{2n+2} = P_{2n+1} \cup \bigcup_{\mathfrak{p} \in \mathfrak{P},a \in P_{2n+1}} p \circ a
$$